# IE7 showing background-color in div with bg img despite stating 'transparent'

Tags: css, transparency, background-image, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to get my site to behave in IE7 (how much I am starting to hate IE I can't even begin to explain). Here's the site:

http://tiger.directrouter.co.uk/~millbank/?page_id=21

As you can see, the quotes have a grey background in IE7 but not in other browsers. Any idea how I can get around this? The quotes aren't fading in when you first visit the page like they should be (this works in other browsers).

Thanks,

osu

Comment: Nobody can see the page, as it's password-protected by Wordpress. Mind posting your CSS and HTML?

Comment: quotes? I dont see any thing except a login page?

Comment: I can see the page now but it would be best for everyone (incl. future readers) to have your relevant code posted within the OP.

Comment: Apologies, I tried to remove that password as soon as possible, but I guess you guys got there before I did that! Please try again now

Comment: @Sparky672 - totally agree, here's the CSS I'm using for the quotes: http://www.pastie.org/2145619 and here's the HTML: http://pastie.org/2145640

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this

```
background-color: rgb(77, 77, 79);
```

from all the 5 divs. When you remove this in-line style, the grey background is removed in IE7. Also it is properly fading as it does in IE9.

Comment: @Osu: You have some additional problems in IE7 such as the position of the Credentials Text.

Comment: Thanks for this - after you said the problem is with inline styles, I realised that the answer lies with jQuery cycle - you need to set `cleartypeNoBg: true` in Cycle (see here for more: http://bit.ly/knilho). I'll look into the text positioning on credentials as well.

Comment: sorted now I think, the problem with the background was due to Cycle as stated above and the positioning was because IE7 incorrectly strips margins out from a div when it is placed within an absolutely positioned div. Love it. I swear M$ do this on purpose to destroy web developers' lives!

Comment: @Osu: LOL. Yeah they do that, dont they. Happy it worked out for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try taking out the background-color in the conditional CSS for IE7 and less.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #quotes {
            background-color: #010C3D;<!--- REMOVE THIS LINE
            background-image:none;
        }
        .qdown, .qup {
            background-image:none;
        }
        .quote-text {
            padding:20px 20px 0 20px;   
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for getting back to me - I've removed this now (I was trying to find out why a background colour was appearing hence the conditionals). Problem is that there is a background colour in there by default in IE that I can't seem to remove...

Comment: Have you been using IE developer to try turning on and off CSS styles to see which one is causing the interference?

Comment: @ Brian Hoover - I used IE's developer tools to check it out and can see it's jQuery Cycle that is forcing the bg colour. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have some conditionals css for IE within the "quotes" div, don't you?

Try to move them all to  or move them below the "quotes" div.

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work - I've removed the conditional comments for the timebeing so it's clearer what the problem is